# Add catogory to Elementor

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

I am working on a WordPres plugin.

Now i want to add an catogory to the elementor plugin.

I can't find out how to do this from my plugin only.

**My current code:**

```
add_action( 'elementor/elements/categories_registered', 'add_elementor_widget_categories' );
function add_elementor_widget_categories( $elements_manager ) {
 $elements_manager->add_category(
    ' first-category',
     [
         'title' => __( 'First Category', 'plugin-name' ),
         'icon' => 'fa fa-plug',
     ]
 );
 $elements_manager->add_category(
     'second-category',
     [
         'title' => __( 'Second Category', 'plugin-name' ),
         'icon' => 'fa fa-plug',
     ]
 );
}
```

Does anyone know how to do what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code was corract all along the only thing was that there where no widgets attached to it. Big mistake on me!

Answer (score 0):

Now Simply add any widget in this category ::

```
public function get_categories() {

    return [ 'first-category' ];

}
```